# Source of Microsoft Streaming Service Proxy device (and others)

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, device-manager

I seem to have 3 sound devices on my Windows 10 installation that I haven't really seen before, called "Microsoft Streaming Service Proxy", "Microsoft Streaming Quality Manager Proxy" and "Microsoft Streaming Clock Proxy". These 3 devices seem to be randomly dis- and re-connecting, and causing the windows "hardware removed" sound to be played.

Search engines don't seem to be helpful: I can't identify where these devices are coming from and why do they keep disconnecting randomly every few minutes.

I tried manually showing hidden devices in the device manager, then uninstalling them, but they come back eventually. Using PnPWatcher I am able to see some (but not all) of these disconnected events:

[image: disconnected events]

Does anyone know what are these for / what's causing them to exist? I'm hoping this information will help me get rid of them.

Comment: (1) Is or was your computer ever connected to a domain? (2) What is your audio device? (3) What is the driver of the audio device? (4) Is the Internet information services (IIS) Windows feature installed?

Comment: 1: no; 2: primary is a schiit modius DAC but there are a few others (nvidia outputs, motherboard realtek audio, rode mic output); 3: service proxy is MSKSSRV.sys and ksthunk.sys, clock proxy is MSPCLOCK.sys and ks..., quality manager proxy is MSPQM.sys and ks...; 4: not enabled in extra windows features, visual studio probably installed IIS express but it's not running in any way

Comment: I think that MSKSSRV is only used if no other audio driver exists.

Comment: Have you checked that you have audio drivers for all your devices (from the manufacturer)?

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell everything else is correct.

Comment: Do you have Microsoft Teams installed?

Comment: I do. But I had it installed on previous machines too and a) don't recall seeing these devices b) never had this random disconnect issue

Comment: As a test, could you uninstall Teams for the moment?

Comment: I have uninstalled teams, the devices seem to remain in the device manager (although I guess most of the time they are also "disconnected" so I don't know if the uninstaller would explicitly remove them)

Comment: Update: random disconnect sounds still persist after removing teams

Comment: If it's a device disconnect sound, see [this article](https://www.maketecheasier.com/stop-random-usb-connect-noises-windows/) on how to detect which device. As a last resort, you may just [disable the sounds](https://www.technipages.com/windows-10-fix-device-disconnect-sounds).

Comment: I have tried all the reasonable solutions in that and other articles. I am using PnPWatcher to monitor for plugnplay events and that's where I know these 3 things are causing the issues

Comment: Try : In Device Manager to delete your true sound device (Realtek?) with its driver, then reboot.

Comment: sadly that did not help either :(

Answer (score 0):

Those are related to Microsoft Stream, the successor of Office 365 Streaming. Last Update-distribution for the switch to MS Stream startet in March 2022.

As long as you want to use a Webcam expecially for Streaming or Videocalls keep them running. If your Webcam won´t work Delete those three an reconnect the camera.